# Как перенести настройки IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Как перенести настройки IntelliJ IDEA или же при переустановке системы сделать резервное сохранение настроек программы?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html

Comment: или сохраните директорию .IntellijIdeaXX из home dir

Answer (score 5, accepted):

File -> Export Settings. Выбираете что сохранять, сохраняете, в новой системе там же выбираете Import Settings

*--------------Update August 2021*

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Settings... - Выбираем что сохранить - выгружаем в архив.
File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Import Settings... - Загружаем настройки из архива.

Comment: А что если я хочу все настройки сохранить, какую папку выбирать?

Comment: Любую откуда потом можно будет выбрать файл с сохраненными настройками. В одной из последних версий появилась возможность сохранять настройки в удаленный репозиторий (gtihub например).

Answer (score 2):

Актуальная информация на версии 2020+ Idea

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Export Settings...

*(специально проверил для Android Studio и  Idea)*

[image]